# redefine the table of contents normal chapter and the appendix format

Tags: table-of-contents

I redefine the table of contents, but I dont want to the appenix changed,

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{.5\baselineskip}\bfseries}
{*** \thecontentslabel ***\quad}{}
{\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[10pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}
```

[image]
the codes as:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[bf,indentafter,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}


\titleformat{\chapter}
{\filcenter\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\chaptertitlename~} {0.5em} {}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{*4}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{.5\baselineskip}\bfseries}
{*** \thecontentslabel ***\quad}{}
{\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[10pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[2em]{\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}
{\S\thecontentslabel\quad}{}
{\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[10pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{title}
\section{aaa}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{title}
\section{aaaa}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{title}
\lipsum[1-3]

\appendix
\chapter{title}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{title}
\lipsum[1-3]
one two three four
\backmatter
\chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method to solve this problem, just after **\appendix** redefine the format.

```
\appendix
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{.1\baselineskip}\bfseries}
{new format \thecontentslabel\quad}{}
{\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[5pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}
```